# A diabetic contact of herpes zoster patient

Tags: disease-transmission, infectious-diseases, disease, herpes

Should a patient of herpes zoster who successfully take medications for a month (pain and rash disappear) avoid contact with a diabetic patient and what are the precautions when dealing with each other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the CDC it depends if the virus is active or not, and they define active as:

> A person with active shingles can spread the virus when the rash is in the blister-phase. A person is not infectious before the blisters appear. Once the rash has developed crusts, the person is no longer contagious.

The CDC also comments on transmission risk of active shingles:

> Shingles is less contagious than chickenpox and the risk of a person with shingles spreading the virus is low if the rash is covered.

[Here's](http://www.cdc.gov/shingles/about/transmission.html) the CDC info that also includes recommendations for preventing transmission of shingles.

They don't mention any specific precautions (other than the general ones on their site) for diabetics.